# Difference in logistic regression result when using StandardScaler

Tags: python, pandas, logistic-regression

I have a dataframe: `df = pd.read_excel` I did `classifier.predict(df)`
And another thing I tried is doing `df = sc.transform(df)` and then doing 
`classifier.predict(df)` The result was different. What could be the reason for this
Which one is accurate?

I am using Logistic regression :

```
#Fitting Logistic Regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state =0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test out which model is more accurate by using cross_val_score from sckit-learn(See documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html)

In my belief, the one where you applied the scaler to the dataframe is the more accurate one. This is because Logistic Regression assumes a linear relationship between the input variables and with the output, as it essentially a Linear Regression algorithm with a sigmoid function. Scaling your data helps expose that linear relationship better.